# React Native Notification

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app requires the following Firebase features

1. Cloud Messaging
2. Analytics
3. Crashlytics

I found quite a few libraries online that support this and [React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) seems like the most complete package so far that produces native code.

For Cloud Messaging I would like to handle the notifications, ie when i receive an fcm that contains a data message, I would like to handle it manually. The official react native framework has `PushNotificationIOS` that lets you handle it but there is no such thing for android.

I have searched and found that [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) does that but it also has support for push notifications which I am already getting from the library above, I do not want to add another library with the same features as that would unnecessarily increase the size of the app. Is there a standalone library that will let me handle creation of notifications locally for android and iOS?

Another thing I noticed is not a lot of libraries currently support creation of channel for notifications which is a problem since Oreo and above versions of android make it mandatory to have a channel without which notifications do not work.

Comment: use react-native-fcm